# Django: How to create a field with many booleanfields?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I am trying to create a days_of_week model for my alarm app where users can just select the days of the week they want the alarm to go off. I want to use checkboxInput widget for it, but I can't find a way to find a field like that. Can someone show me how to make a field like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CommaSeparatedIntegerField. More info in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/

Comment: Answers that have only a link are not useful if the linked page ever goes down. Could you at least summarize what the page says?

Comment: @SiKing The answer is to use a `CommaSeparatedIntegerField`. It is a short, but useful answer with or without the link.

Comment: He is right, CommaSeparatedIntegerField is actually what I was looking for, except not in a checkbox format

Comment: You can use checkbox format with CommaSeparatedIntegerField, but you have to define this with the widget in the form. This link can help you: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2051/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a checkboxselectmultiple: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#checkboxselectmultiple

short example:

```
select = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

where CHOICES would be your days of the week.

Comment: Excuse me. i missed that you needed it in a model. not a form
But why dont you put 7 booleanfield in your model. its not that you need an n-length amount?

Comment: Currently I have 7 BooleanFields, but it is aligned vertically in the admin page because they are 7 different fields, and I want it to be aligned horizontally instead